# Return generated Typekit id in Yeoman Generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm using [node-typekit](https://github.com/bramstein/node-typekit) to create a new Typekit empty font set in my Yeoman generator for use in my project. I am able to successfully create the kit, but cannot figure out how to return the kit id value back to the Yeoman generator so I can add the necessary Typekit script tag values to my web pages. Here is the part of my index.js generator script in question:

At the top of index.js:

```
var kit = require('typekit');
var typekitID = '';

function setTypekitID(theid) {
    typekitID = theid;
};
```

And the app section:

```
app: function () {

  var token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
  var split = this.domainname.split('.');
  split.pop();
  var localdomain = split.join('.') + '.dev';

  kit.create(token, {
    name: this.appname,
    badge: false,
    domains: [this.domainname, localdomain],
    families: []
  }, function (err, data) {
    setTypekitID(data.kit.id);
  });

}
```

If instead of:

```
setTypekitID(data.kit.id);
```

I use:

```
console.log(data.kit.id);
```

The correct kit ID is displayed in the console. However, I can't quite figure out how to pass the data.kit.id value in the callback back to the generator for further use. Given the current code above, it comes back as "undefined".

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any experience with `typekit`, I would guess that `kit.create` is an asynchronous call. When you make such a call, the generator needs to know about it, so it can delay invocation of further methods until it knows your asynchronous callback has had a chance to execute.

Try doing this:

```
app: function () {
  var done = this.async(); // this tells the generator, "hang on, yo."
  // ...
  kit.create(token, { /* ... */ }, function (err, data) {
    setTypekitID(data.kit.id);

    done(); // calling this resumes the generator.
  });
}
```

An example of how the default `generator-generator` uses this can be found [here](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-generator/blob/master/app/templates/app/index.js#L20).

Comment: That did it! Thanks Stephen. Handling that async task was giving me quite the headache. Much appreciated!